# Convert a String to ZonedDateTime in UTC

Tags: java, date

I have a `String` which contains date in `ZonedDateTime` - UTC format. Example :-

```
2020-08-21T02:05:45.231Z
```

I want to convert it to a **variable** of type `ZonedDateTime`. What should be the pattern on the formatter?

(Note the time ending in "Z" which indicates UTC)

Comment: Simply use parse `ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T02:05:45.231Z");`

Comment: Traycho your answers are helpful and to the point, please include in the answers section so that i can approve them ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to this example `String` being in ISO format with a valid time zone abbreviation, you can directly **parse it without passing a pattern**.

Just like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T02:05:45.231Z");
    System.out.println(zdt);
}
```

The output is then (again) the ISO-formatted `String`

```
2020-08-21T02:05:45.231Z
```

**Please note** that an `OffsetDateTime` should be preferred here because UTC is not a real time zone, it is the *Coordinated Universal Time*, the time without an offset.
The code is just slightly different:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T02:05:45.231Z");
    System.out.println(odt);
}
```

with exactly the same output.

For the sake of completeness, this is how to parse your example `String` to an `Instant`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant instant = Instant.parse("2020-08-21T02:05:45.231Z");
    System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli());
}
```

This time, the output is the very same moment in time represented by epoch milliseconds (milliseconds since `1970-01-01'T'00:00:00.000...`):

```
1597975545231
```

Comment: I’d prefer parsing into either an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime`. I know a `ZonedDateTime` was asked for, but it doesn’t make that much sense here since we haven’t got any time zone.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`.

```
jshell> DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.parse("2020-08-21T02:05:45.231Z")
=> {InstantSeconds=1597975545, OffsetSeconds=0},ISO resolved to 2020-08-21T02:05:45.231
```

Comment: That's the formatter which is used internally when parsing without a formatter, so good point to mention the explicit use...